# What are the bad things that V8 Memory limitation can cause in a Node.js app?

Tags: multithreading, node.js, ffmpeg

I've read several things about V8 Memory Limitation. Alas, I'm still not clear with it. Maybe it's clear but I don't want to believe. Here is my question:

I have a Node.js application which will be hosted in a single physical server. This app will basically be an interface for some video related CPU and RAM heavy jobs. For example, I use FFMPEG to transcode videos within this application. And when doing this, I use `child_process`es of Node. Especially `.spawn`.

My question is;
Since I'm running CPU and RAM intensive jobs inside a child_process, will I hook up to V8 Memory Limit (in a properly set 64bit system it's 1.7GB)?

Because my FFMPEG processes will exhaust almost all resources of the server in production. Depending on the server configuration, it may use even 32GB of ram and tens of virtual CPU cores.

I think I need some explanation on how `child_process`es work.

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Child processes themselves do not affect V8's memory usage. However if you are buffering in memory a very large output from the child process, that buffer will be constrained by V8's memory limits.

What I mean by buffering is:

```
exec('produce --a-gigabyte-of-stdout-output', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
});
```

or doing a similar thing with child_process.spawn():

```
var proc = spawn('produce', [ '--a-gigabyte-of-stdout-output' ]);
var buf = '';
proc.stdout.on('data', function(d) {
  buf += d;
});
```

If you're doing something like this right now, you might want to try streaming the data from the child process to somewhere else instead of buffering inside the node process.

Comment: Could you give some detail about this `buffer`ing stuff? Maybe a small example?

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? Anyway, I've updated the answer to include examples of buffering that could cause issues with the V8 memory limit.

Comment: Thanks for the update mscdex! I guessed  you will think that's me :) No, it's not me who down voted you. I'm accepting your answer, thank you! But I'm still not clear how to stream stdout from inside of a child_process?..`'produce', [ '--a-gigabyte-of-stdout-output' ]` this is just a unix command?